# Import JS file to make its variables part of the global scope of file that is importing them?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a js file (1) filled with variables and I want to import all the variables from the file (1) to another js file (2), for organization purposes, so that these variables make part of the global scope of the js file (2).

I tried "import/export * from [path]" with no success. I can import individual files with the export/import but then I have to call it with "importName.variable" which ends up making the process  more complicated with more variables.

I know I could just add the script files to the html as tags and I would get the desired results, but are there any downsides to putting the script files on the html instead of importing them from the js files? Is this the only way of doing what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ES6 modules, the only way to do something like this would be to make the variables *completely* global. In the other file, do something like:

```
window.someVarName = 'someValue';
```

Otherwise, you'll have to write out all the values explicitly when importing, eg:

```
export const someVarName = 'someValue';
```

```
import { someVarName } from './theFileName.js';
```

The second approach is highly recommended. Having an explicit dependency chain makes code a lot more manageable. It might take a bit longer to write, but in large applications, it'll make things so much easier to maintain.

There's no way to make variables exported in one file visible to the whole contents of another file without

- making the variables global *everywhere*, or
- explicitly importing the variables, either individually or as the whole module's namespace

> are there any downsides to putting the script files on the html instead of importing them from the js files?

Yes, it'll make the variables global everywhere, which will make a large application more difficult to maintain and understand.

Comment: Thank you very much, how would I go about importing the whole module since "import *" doesn't work even though I saw some people saying to do just that around here. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `import` will work fine if you're using ES6 modules. Make sure the root script is using `<script type="module">`, then you can do `import { someVarName } from './theFileName.js';` where `theFileName.js` is the relative path to the other script file

Comment: This certainly works, I might have misspoke, what I meant is `import * from 'filename'` where by `*` I mean the entire content from the file and then I would also have to `export *` I guess. Thanks.

Comment: With `*`, the syntax is `import * as theNamespace from '...'` That will put all the exported members of the other file into a variable called `theNamespace`. Then you can access values of it like any other object, eg `theNamespace.someVarName`

Comment: Thanks this has helped me hone down the possible solutions and find out that my problem was the export. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: excellent answer @CertainPerformance +1, so when we import some functionality it only lives in the "global scope top-level" of that file that imported that other functionality, right?